# Why FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback not responding in foreground service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-fingerprint-api

Why [FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback) not responding in foreground service?

**Code**

```
//Inside onStartCommand method
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
startForeground(NotificationControl.notificationId, NotificationControl.builderOfNotification(this, false).build());

FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback authenticationCallback = new FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
        Toast.makeText(ForegroundService.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString) {
        super.onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString);
        Toast.makeText(ForegroundService.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
        Toast.makeText(ForegroundService.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        Toast.makeText(ForegroundService.this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
fingerprintManager.authenticate(null, null, 0, authenticationCallback, null);
```

It's working well if the activity was running but if I destroy the actvity, the listeners above not responding, Why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, After hours of trying I found the problem, The solution is you must create [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) and enable the permission from settings, After enabling the permission, Callback will work.